# Postgres on Conflict Update With Default Column Expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

In case a column has a default value expression

```
create table A (
...
b numeric default cos(54)
)
```

Is it possible for `on conflict` statement reset the column with the default expression without

- copy-paste the expression it self
- using **default** as a value while composing excluded record it self

I.e. just to refer the **default** exactly from the update statement. Something like

```
on conflict
update set b = default
```

or even

```
on conflict
update set b = case when some_condition then default else A.b end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `DEFAULT` value in an upsert statement:

```
INSERT INTO t (foo,bar) VALUES (1,2)
ON CONFLICT (foo) DO UPDATE
SET bar = DEFAULT;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e3cae854e3196c0543699554d18ef5d0)